# sequelize findall attrib searching

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

How can I output all the data from a column at once, without using (map) and (forEach)

| Column |
| --- |
| one |
| two |
| three |

// one two three

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your request attributes property. This gives you only one column

```
where:{
attributes:['columnName']
}
```